# JavaFX CSS: Images in a separate folder cannot be found

Tags: css, png, javafx-2, filepath

I am trying to make a java applet using the javaFX library, but i have run into an unusual problem. I have CSS formatted toggle buttons that use png images, but when i put the images into an images folder the program is unable to locate them.
The problem line is:

```
-fx-border-image-source: url("left-btn.png");

// versus

-fx-border-image-source: url("images/left-btn.png");
// or
-fx-border-image-source: url("./images/left-btn.png");
```

As long as the images are in the same folder as the java class using them, it works fine, but as soon as they are moved into an images folder the classes cannot find them. The CSS file can be moved and still found but the images cannot. The second two lines above as well as any variations of them that I have been able to come up with fail to find the png files.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is images folder located?

Comment: The folder is in the same directory as all of the working files. The current setup that works is to have all of the files in the same folder, the .class, .css, and .png's. We want to, for the sake of clarity and organization, put the .png's into an images folder in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

in case since its not answered yet:

-fx-border-image-source: url("../images/left-btn.png");

when the imagefolder is on the same level as the folder for your classes

Comment: Thanks, but we tried that too. We think the problem was that the parent class was using a style sheet and ignoring any inline style changes. We bypassed the problem by altering the objects instead of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is (when image is 1 level up and inside folder "images"):

```
.image-background {
     -fx-background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
}
```